# How to start ArrayList from the specific index?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

If i have an ArrayList of

```
Sun
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
```

then, today is Thu, so i want it to look like

```
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
```

I am using recyclerView to show the arrayList of the week days. Please help me out.

Comment: read about `%` operator in java

Comment: @Kabindra Shrestha: Assign priority to every day in your model object and sort your arraylist according to priority!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    int todayIndex = list.indexOf("Thu");
    int index = (todayIndex+1)%7;
    while(index!= todayIndex) {
        System.out.println(list.get(index));
        index = (index+1)%7;
    }
```

Comment: @Kabindra Shrestha: It's effective solution!!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do like this

```
list.add(1, "Fri")
list.add(2, "Sat")
list.add(3, "Sun")
list.add(4, "Mon")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `List` Interface offers a `subList` method. You should be able to use that:

```
int tomorrowIndex = 1 + weekDays.indexOf("Thu");
if (tomorrowIndex < weekDays.size()) {
    List<String> previousDays = weekDays.subList(0, tomorrowIndex);
    weekDays.addAll(previousDays);
    previousDays.clear();
}
```

Alternatively build a new `List` from the two sub lists:

```
List<String> newOrder = new ArrayList<String>(weekDays.size());
int tomorrowIndex = 1 + weekDays.indexOf("Thu");
if (tomorrowIndex < weekDays.size()) {
    newOrder.addAll(weekDays.subList(tomorrowIndex, weekDays.size());
}
newOrder.addAll(weekDays.subList(0, tomorrowIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hi  Tested Code*

```
                ArrayList<String> updatedList =new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> newList =getList();
                int todayIndex = newList.indexOf("Thu")+1;
                if(todayIndex<newList.size()){
                    List<String> firstPart = newList.subList(0, todayIndex);
                    List<String> secondPartPart =  newList.subList(todayIndex, newList.size());         
                    updatedList.addAll(secondPartPart);
                    updatedList.addAll(firstPart);
                }else{
                    updatedList =newList;
                }
                mRootView.setAdapter(new FakePageAdapter(updatedList));
```

**Let me know if not work**

Comment: I'm afraid your creation of firstPart will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if the element in question is the last in the newList